# jQuery Equivalent of following

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have checked Google but cannot find it:

```
document.getElementsByName("laminar[col0][]")
```

Comment: [Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

Comment: Can you post the element html which you want to find.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[Attribute Equals Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)**:

```
$('[name="laminar\\[col0\\]\\[\\]"]') // you need to use \\ to escape special characters
```

or wrap your value inside double quotes without escaping:

```
$('[name="laminar[col0][]"]')
```

or:

```
var name = "laminar[col0][]";  
$('[name="'+ name + '"]');
```

Comment: You dont need to escape brackets when you quote it. `$('[name="laminar[col0][]"]')` works fine

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a jQuery object, you can always pass a list of nodes to jQuery:

```
$(document.getElementsByName("laminar[col0][]"));
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-elementArray

Comment: @VisioN Can you please explain why? jQuery is doing pretty much the same internally for any selector you pass to it.

Comment: Because the better practice is either to use jQuery or to use pure JS, but not a mixture of both in such a primitive case. It will just drop the performance. Moreover, AFAIK, jQuery will probably use other alternatives, like CSS query selector.

Comment: @VisioN Not at all. Looking up elements with the native methods is a lot faster than jQuery's selector engine. Here is a jsperf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-nodelist-vs-selector

Comment: Sorry, by performance I meant the development performance, not the execution speed. That works well for the simple queries like that, but if you need to add more complexity to the selector and to pick the elements with certain name within other elements or whatever, the pure JS complexity will start to increase (if not using newest `querySelector`), while in jQuery you can write that in a couple of extra bytes. So if you start to replace all bits that you don't know how to write correctly in jQuery with pure JS, we'll lose the general idea of jQuery's easiness.